# How to create Google Calendar event by email-username authentication?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-api, google-calendar-api

I need to create google calendar events from my application, based on logged user. For each user I have email/password of the gmail account. From my searches, every guide is for creating events to just one gmail account like here: [OAuth 2.0 Google API access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) but this is not my case.
Has anyone ever faced this issue?

Comment: Do you want to add calendar events to each user specific calendar?

Comment: Yes, the logged user, can click 'AddToCalendar' and I want to automatically create the event, since I have email/pass for that.

Comment: Well I think this would not work. Some months ago I wrote an application which creates events in my calendar. But to achieve this I had to create and register an application in the Google Developers Console and grant access to my own calendar. In other words: You can only write an application which modifies your own calendar. Regardless of weather you have the user/password of each user.

Comment: I saw that in previous versions it was possible to do this, but it seems now they only let you do it this way. Too bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Login and password to access a users Google calendar account.  This is called client login and was shut down by [google may 2015](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/02/reminder-clientlogin-shutdown-scheduled.html).

You have a few options.  First you can add an event to a calendar you own personally then add the different users as attendees using their email address they will get an email and be able to click the email and add it to their personal google calendar account.

Switch to Oauth2 you do not need to be storing a users login and password to their Google account you cant use it for anything.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I don't understand why did they shut it down!

Comment: I am using oauth2. How do I create events in different user's calendars? How can they authorize my application?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2  Sorry I am not a java developer so cant help to much with code.  Try this then open a new question if you have issues